# Do SPY returns include dividends?

Tags: united-states, stocks, financial-literacy, stock-analysis

Looking at a chart of SPY on finance.yahoo.com from March 1 - Nov 30, 2018, it returned +1.67 (+0.61%). Does the +0.61% include dividends?

Looking at the historical data, dividends are displayed https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SPY/history?p=SPY but I'm not sure if the 0.61% number needs to be adjusted in some way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The one day change in the SPY from 11/29 to 11/30 is + $1.67  (+0.61%).  It is not the return for the period of  March 1 - Nov 30, 2018.

Yahoo provides the actual close and the adjusted close.  For example, if you bought 100 share of SPY at the 9/20 close of $293.58 then close on 9/21 would be $291.99.  9/21 was the ex-div date for $1.323.  Your equity position would be down $1.59 but you would be receiving $1.323 on the Pay Date. Therefore, your actual loss was 27 cents.

The adjusted close takes the dividend into account.  $291.99 from 9/21 less $292.26 from 9/22 is the same loss of 27 cents.

Reinvesting the dividends would change these numbers slightly because each reinvested dividend would have a different cost basis.  Not reinvesting the dividends for March 1 to Nov 30, 2018 would have performed slightly better because 2 of the 3 dividends received during this time period would have been reinvested at higher prices.

Comment: So I the simple answer is that +0.61% does not account for reinvested dividends?

Comment: The simple answer is that +.61% is the one day change in the SPY from 11/29 to 11/30.   There are no dividends to account for.

Comment: What does that say about the period from 3/1 - 11/30? Still +.61?

Comment: @4thSpace: It doesn’t say much at all. If I tell you that it rained yesterday, can you know whether it was a dry or wet summer?

Comment: If you bought stock for $10 Friday morning and it was up $1 by the end of the day, you made up 10%.  If your  stock  paid 3 dividends earlier this year,  what do those dividends have to do with your 10% gain?  Nothing.  It's the same deal with your question.  SPY was up .61% on Friday.  Period.  End of story.

Comment: @BobBaerker: I guess we can keep going around in circles but you still haven't answered the question - what was the total return from 3/1 to 11/30? There is a return. If you put in $10k, you got back x and there is a return on that.

Comment: You keep confusing the one day Rate of Change (ROC) of +.61% with the return over a period of time.  When you figure out the difference, you'll be able to frame a sensible question.  If you want to know the Total Return from 3/1 to 11/30, do the math based on the data in your link.  If that's too difficult, a DRIP calculator will do it for you;  All you have to do is plug in the dates.  Here's one that coincidentally calculates ROI on $10k with and without dividend reinvestment: https://www.dividendchannel.com/drip-returns-calculator/

Comment: Interesting. I thought the return displayed was for the time range but I see it is only for a day. No idea why they don't display the percentage for the time range.

Comment: The quote at the top of the page is the current value of the SPY.  During trading hours it's live.  The next number to the right is the change since yesterday's close and the next number is the percent change since yesterday's close.  After the market closes, the quote is static.

Answer (score 0):

As Bob (correctly!) responded, SPY does not include dividends.

Yahoo offers a look at the S&P [Total return ^SP500TR](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5ESP500TR?p=%5ESP500TR) which easily lets you calculate the total return between two dates. The only downside is this started in 1988.

Comment: It shows +.84%, just a little more then SPY. I'm guessing it has factored in the dividend.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the reason for the .84%.  Reason is more likely that all index funds (including SPY) have fees/expenses.  So they have to be deducted from the return, thus producing a slight under-performance as compared to the index (in this case, the S&P 500).  If dividends are included on one and not the other, the difference would be much greater as the S&P 500 has historically returned dividends as measured in the hundreds of bp's per year.

Comment: If this was intended to be a reply to the comment under Joe Taxpayer's answer then it should have been a comment there.  If not, then this has nothing to do with the OP's question.